# How to install Ubuntu 15 with Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, 15.04

How do I have to make the partitions with Ubuntu 15.0 thus I can choose from the Boot Sector when I turn on the pc. I want to install ubuntu 15.0 with windows 8.1. I have a notebook with a hard disk with 3 partitions: C: with windows 8.1, D: with my personal information with windows and E: only for Ubuntu. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into your Ubuntu LiveUSB/CD. In the setup, choose `Something Else` when prompted where to install Ubuntu. Next, double-click your partition meant for Ubuntu. For the `Type` option (or something similar), select the `ext4` option from the dropdown. Select to format it and write `/` as the mount point. Click OK and then Next. Ubuntu will install to that partition.